# Right biceps is bigger than left biceps!

Tags: biceps

I was basically very thin but started putting on weight recently by doing regular exercises.

I do exercises for my biceps as well.  Although I do same number of repetitions for both hands, recently I have observed that my right biceps is a 0.5 to 0.6 inch bigger than the left one.

I am really worried about this and I am not quite sure as to continue with exercises or just stop it!!!

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't stop.  It's not unusual to have one side of your body to be slightly stronger than the other.

This is likely to be true, even if you don't workout.

Think about it, if you are right haned, you will automatically use your right hand for most tasks you do.  Therefore you are likely to be slightly stronger on that side of the body.

When working out, always use the same weight for both sides of your body.  Ie don't use a heavier weight for your stronger arm.  Always work at the weight level of the weaker arm, and hopefully things will level out a bit.

Comment: Happy to hear that its not unusual :) Thanks mate..!!

Comment: "This is likely to be true, even if you don't workout." Surely it's *more* likely to be true if you don't workout. People are naturally going to use their dominant hand for anything that doesn't require both arms, so most of your lifting and carrying in day to day life will be with one side of your body. People who workout, on the other hand, are generally training both equally, reducing the difference between the two.